# CookiePolicyOptions' does not contain a definition for CheckConsentNeeded

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, .net-core, debian, signalr

I am implementing SignalR using dotnet core on visual studio code
on Linux debian ,and following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio-code) tutorial (working at the time of posting).

Inside the startup class I got this error message.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookiepolicyoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article **CookiePolicyOptions** class does contain the property **CheckConsentNeeded** which is used to check consent policy.

I am unable to solve this please help.

[image]

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookiepolicyoptions.checkconsentneeded?view=aspnetcore-2.1), this property is new for ASP.NET Core **v2.1**, you are sure you are using that (and not still 2.0)?

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy -Version 2.1.2